# fixing the git rebase

Tags: git, bash

I have changes on my code, while my teammate also has changes on their part
I made a commit, the same as theirs, so we end up changing most of the files

After pushing his branch, and then I pull it,

I got this message from git bash.

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Fixed the account control problem
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       application/views/templates/header.php
.git/rebase-apply/patch:417: trailing whitespace.
<?php
.git/rebase-apply/patch:418: trailing whitespace.
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
.git/rebase-apply/patch:427: trailing whitespace.
$autoload['libraries'] = array('ion_auth');
.git/rebase-apply/patch:436: trailing whitespace.
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
.git/rebase-apply/patch:451: trailing whitespace.
$config['tables']['groups']          = 'groups';
warning: squelched 772 whitespace errors
warning: 777 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging application/views/templates/header.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in application/views/templates/header.php
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Fixed the account control problem
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort"
```

The problem is, git display files unstaged and when I tried to commit it, I cannot continue rebasing, if I ran, git rebase --skip, files I pulled also lost.

What is the proper solution to this? this is the first time I encounter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I speculate that when you did a pull, you actually did `git pull --rebase`, i.e. pull in rebase mode.  This means that you rebased your local branch on top of the version which exists on the remote.  The general way to complete the rebase is to take the following steps, for each file which appears as being in `CONFLICT`:

- resolve the merge conflicts in the file manually
- do `git add` on each file
- when all conflicts have been resolved, then do `git rebase --continue`

The good news is that the step of the rebase which you showed us only has `header.php` as being in conflict.  However, each step of the rebase corresponds to reapplying one of your local commits, and it is possible that there could be conflicts in more than one file during a subsequent step of the rebase.

Given that you may have made a mess of your current rebase attempt, you might want to `git rebase --abort` and then pull again.

An alternative would be to pull using merge as the strategy.  This would just be a single step and would result in all files having a conflit show up all at once.  But perhaps your organization is enforcing a rebase workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Open `application/views/templates/header.php`.

Remove "HEAD" and "======" like statements.

Do `git add application/views/templates/header.php` to add `header.php` to the index

run `git rebase --continue`

Comment: You forgot the `git add` step, and there could be multiple files in conflict should there be other commits which need to be reapplied.

Comment: Solving a conflict doesn't mean just removing the "=======" lines. They are markers around the two versions of the changed code. If you only remove those lines most probably you end up with a mess. For each conflict you have to carefully choose the version of the code that fits your needs: it can be yours or your work mate's but, most of the times, it's a combination of them. You better use a [visual diff & merge tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+diff+and+merge+tool) to merge the files.

Answer (score 0):

After pulling remote branch, conflicting in some files. If you want to keep `remote/changes` then accept `--theirs` otherwise accept `--ours`.

```
$ git pull origin <branch-name>

$ git checkout --theirs -- .             # accept remote (--theirs) changes
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Fix conflicts'
$ git push origin HEAD
```